# Plot[func,...] shows incorrect function, but ListPlot@Table[func,...] is correct

Tags: plotting, units

When trying to Plot the function

```
1/(1 + E^(((e + Quantity[-7.05, "Electronvolts"]) 
  *(Quantity[1, 1/("BoltzmannConstant")]))/T))
```

I get an incorrect plot looking like[image: incorrect Plot]

However, if I first evaluate the points with Table and then use ListLinePlot it works as expected

[image: correct Table@ListPlot]

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to keep the units in the definition of `f`, but the following works: `f[e_, T_] := 1/(1 + E^(((e + -7.05)*1)/T))`. A good start when `Plot` returns an empty plot is to evaluate the function for some arbitrary values. Try and you'll understand why nothing plots.

Comment: If you really must have units: `With[{T = 5000}, Plot[1/(1 + E^(((Quantity[e, "Electronvolts"] + Quantity[-7.05, "Electronvolts"])*(Quantity[1, 1/("BoltzmannConstant")]))/Quantity[T, "Kelvins"])) // Evaluate, {e, 1, 20}]]`

Comment: @anderstood Whenever `Plot` returns nothing I always evaluate the function for arbitrary values.  That's why, after `Plot` failed, I replaced `Plot` with `Table`.  As you can see, evaluating the function for arbitrary values in `Table` works.  And when I `ListPlot` those arbitrary values, the function works.  My question was why `Plot` fails when the function successfully evaluates for arbitrary values.

Answer (score 1):

I think a general fix might be using a wrapper function to add the units:

```
fp[t_] := f[Quantity[t, "seconds"]]
Plot[fp[t], {t, 0, 0.004}]
(* instead of *)
Plot[f[t], {t, Quantity[0.0, "Seconds"], Quantity[0.004, "Seconds"]}]
```

The problem seems to be that `Plot` does not always pass the parameter to `f` with units. It seems like `Echo`s are able to show what happens:

```
Plot[Echo[f[Echo[t]]], {t, Quantity[0.0, "Seconds"], Quantity[0.004, "Seconds"]}]
```